# Vizing's Theorem Proof, Kempe Chain

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm trying to follow the proof of Vizing's Theorem given here [https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2015/REUPapers/Green.pdf](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2015/REUPapers/Green.pdf)

Unfortunately, I soon ran into trouble with this line:

> If $c_k$ is absent at $v$, then we can reassign colours $c_i$ to $\{v, w_i\}$ for $i ∈ [k]$ and we are done.

The problem is that ever frustrating when not understood phrase: "we are done".

Suppose we take the very simplest case, where $c_0$ is already absent at $v$. Then we can change $\{v,w_0\}$ to color $c_0$. But then... So what? All we know about $c_0$ is that it was chosen so that it is absent at $w_0$. So how does changing this edge to this color mean 'we are done'?

It would help if I knew what this proof was trying to establish to be 'done'. They're assuming the existence of a counterexample, so of course this has to be a proof by contradiction. They take a minimal counterexample $G$, and then consider an edge $\{v,w_0\}$ that if removed would make the new graph no longer a counterexample; so the natural guess would be that they're trying to show the new graph is still a counterexample, i.e. the edge coloring number of the new graph is still 'too large'. But I don't see how changing the color of the to-be-removed edge in the original graph helps with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although sometimes there's a good reason to write proofs by minimal counterexample, in this proof, it's used gratuitously.

Instead, read the proof as an induction on the number of edges. Initially, we take any edge $e = \{v, w_0\}$ whatsoever. By the induction hypothesis, Vizing's theorem applies to $G-e$, so we take the edge coloring of $G-e$ that this implies. The rest of the proof is explaining how to extend this edge coloring to an edge coloring of $G$ with $\Delta(G)+1$ colors. If we achieve this, then we are done - in the sense that we have proven that Vizing's theorem also applies to $G$, which completes the induction step. By induction, the theorem applies to graphs with any number of edges.

The actual proof is not phrased as a proof by induction, but it's *also* trying to edge-color $G$ by starting from an edge-coloring of $G-e$, which is why I say that it might as well have been a proof by induction. We win by edge-coloring $G$ with $\Delta(G)+1$ colors, since in that case we end up contradicting the assumption that $G$ is a *counterexample*. We used the *minimal* part when we assumed that Vizing's theorem applied to $G-e$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and sorry for slow response. The proof in that link is indeed gratuitous, and what's more has a few errors. I've been trying to write up a clearer version. Currently stuck on the last part: $c_k=c_j$ (the last color in the Kempe chain is the same as a previous color, halting the chain), $c_q$ is not absent from $w_k$ and $w_j$ (a new color absent from $v$ is not absent from the two spokes of the wheel with the offending color overlap). Their argument to fix this is confusing and doesn't seem to apply when $k=1$ (i.e. we hit the repetition immediately).

Comment: We cannot get a repetition immediately. We let $c_0$ be a color absent at $w_0$, pick an edge $\{v, w_1\}$ which has color $c_0$, and let $c_1$ be a color absent at $w_1$. Since $c_0$ is definitely not absent at $w_1$ (the one edge we know out of $w_1$ has color $c_0$), we know that $c_0 \ne c_1$.